# Typescript DefinitelyTyped compilation error TS1005

Tags: typescript

I believe I have the correct setup, but am struggling to get tsc to compile.

My repo branch is https://github.com/inosion/sample-atom-typescript-package/tree/add_react

I have the latest version(s) of typescript - but am not sure what I am doing wrong - `node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(12,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.` etc

```
    ✔ ~/projects/internal/github.com/inosion/sample-atom-typescript-package [master|✚ 3] 
    18:34 $ grep dependencies -A 10 package.json 
      "dependencies": {
        "typescript": "2.3",
        "@types/atom":"*",
        "@types/react":"*",
        "@types/react-native":"*"
      }
    }
    ✔ ~/projects/internal/github.com/inosion/sample-atom-typescript-package [master|✚ 3] 
    18:34 $ tsc --version
    Version 2.7.2
    ✔ ~/projects/internal/github.com/inosion/sample-atom-typescript-package [master|✚ 3] 
    18:34 $ apm clean
    ✔ ~/projects/internal/github.com/inosion/sample-atom-typescript-package [master|✚ 3] 
    18:34 $ tsc --project .
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(12,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(12,75): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(12,99): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,78): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,81): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,97): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,122): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,130): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(14,138): error TS1005: ',' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(27,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(27,49): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(27,50): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(27,68): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(27,69): error TS1005: ')' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(29,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(29,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts(29,57): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2293,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2294,14): error TS1005: ':' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2294,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2295,9): error TS1109: Expression expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2296,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2297,9): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2298,5): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2298,12): error TS1005: ')' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2310,49): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2310,76): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2310,99): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2311,13): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2312,13): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2312,17): error TS1005: ',' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2312,44): error TS1005: ',' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2312,45): error TS1005: ':' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2314,17): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2314,21): error TS1005: ',' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2314,51): error TS1005: ',' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2314,52): error TS1005: ':' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2316,21): error TS1005: '(' expected.
    node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2316,24): error TS1005: ')' expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are getting is on a line with a conditional type (which was [introduced in typescript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)) so this suggests you don't have the latest version (3.0 at the time of writing)

If you look at your output you will also clearly see:

```
18:34 $ tsc --version
Version 2.7.2
```

So the version being used is `2.7` which does not support the features used in the definitions.